# How to check whether the given matrix is a sub matrix of another matrix?

Tags: matrices

I basically want to know whether there is an easy and straight-forward method for checking and if possible, constructing a matrix which avoids a particular matrix.

For example, consider the given matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

If I want to check or construct a matrix that does not contain the given matrix as a sub matrix, is there a straightforward way that allows me to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing a matrix that does not contain a given matrix is easy. First, any matrix of dimensions less than those of the given matrix will obviously fit the bill. Second, any matrix comprised entirely of coefficients that do not occur in the given matrix also works.

How, then, do we recognize whether a given matrix contains another one? This is basically algorithms territory, in particular you can employ any [string searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) to search for the first row of the smaller matrix in each row of the larger one, and if a match is found proceed to test the next row and so on. Many optimizations are possible, e.g. by precomputing a "dictionary" of coefficients that occur in the smaller matrix, leading to [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)-type techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The method that you provided is indeed helpful. I'll read more about it

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as *image registration*. Naive algorithms take quadratic time; algorithms like *phase correlation* use the Fourier transform and take $O(n \log n)$ time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll read more about it

Comment: Could you explain why phase correlation or image registration is related to checking whether one matrix is sub matrix of another matrix? I read articles related to phase correlation and image registration in wikipedia but I cannot find the relationship between image processing and matrix problem.